# python / C# UDP hole punch

Tags: c#, python, sockets, udp

I have tried implementing UDP hole punch from this theory:

A rendezvous server (S) is reachable on UDP by client (A) and client (B).
Clients A and B send a registration package each to S. S reads public IP and outer port and stores it.
S sends A-info (endPointA) to B and B-info (endPointB) to A.
With this information A can send to B's endPoint and B can send to A's endPoint.

server S is python 3 and clients A and B are C#

So far the theory. Here is what works:

- S can send as many messages to A and B as it likes on their public endPoint.
- A and B can send to each other on innerIP:localPort if they are behind the same router ONLY!

Here is what does not work:

- A cannot send to B nor B to A with their public endPointA / endPointB
- even if I create a new socket on the server S, it cannot get a message through to these endPoints

This last limitation makes me think there is some "lock" on routers that only allow the original socket on S to send to the clients(?)

So my question is: what now?

Is there some socket option, socket flag, socket anything that needs to be set to fix this?

I have even tried making a script on the server S that sends to the clients public IP on all ports from 32000-65535 with no messages coming through.

Code for server:

```
def ServerUdpStart(host, port):
"""Start up the server"""
global myServerUdp
success = True
try :
    myServerUdp = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
except socket.error as msg:
    print('UDP Failed to create socket. Error Code:', str(msg[0]), 'Message', msg[1])
    success = False
# Bind socket to local host and port
try:
    myServerUdp.bind( (host, port) )
except socket.error as msg:
    print('UDP bind failed. Error Code : ', str(msg[0]), 'Message', msg[1])
    success = False
return success

def ServerUdpReceiveData():
"""Incoming UDP data (runs in a thread)"""
global myServerUdp
if myServerUdp != None:
    d = myServerUdp.recvfrom(1024)
    data = d[0]
    addr = d[1] # source tuple (ip, port) to store for clients
    if data:
        incomingUdpMessage(addr, data) # handle incoming data
```

Code for a client:

```
public class SocketServerUdpHandler{

    // ports
    private int _port = 0;
    private int _localAssignedPort = 0;
    // udp client
    private UdpClient _clientUdp = null;
    private IPEndPoint recvEndP = new IPEndPoint( IPAddress.Any, 0);

    //********** START **********

    public bool StartUdp(int po){
        // port set by user
        _port = po;
        // client
        bool created = CreateClient();
        // start it up
        if(created){
            FindLocalAssignedPort();
            StartListen();
        }
        return created;
    }

    //********** LISTENER **********

    private bool CreateClient(){
        // state
        bool success = true;
        try{
            // udp client
            _clientUdp = new UdpClient();
        }catch(Exception e){
            success = false;
        }
        return success;
    }

    private void StartListen(){
        // listen
        _clientUdp.BeginReceive(new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), null);
    }

    private void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult ar){
        // read incoming
        byte[] receiveBytes = _clientUdp.EndReceive(ar, ref recvEndP);
        // handle bytes ...
        // listen
        StartListen();
    }

    private void FindLocalAssignedPort(){
        IPEndPoint tmpEndP = new IPEndPoint( IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 10001 );
        byte[] msgByte = new byte[] {(byte) 9};
        _clientUdp.Client.SendTo(msgByte, tmpEndP);
        _localAssignedPort = ((IPEndPoint) _clientUdp.Client.LocalEndPoint).Port;
    }

    //********** SEND TO **********

    public void writeSocketToEndPoint(IPEndPoint ipEndP, byte[] bytes){
        _clientUdp.Client.SendTo(bytes, ipEndP);
    }

}
```